# How to implement the feature on nivo line chart?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement this feature from nivo linechart (https://nivo.rocks/line) where the tooltip always appears on the graph when my cursor in on it, and the tooltip always appears next to a point. Making the tooltip appear always and the transitions between tooltip positions is easy, but i dont understand how does it calculate which point is closest to my pointer, i have taken a look at the source code but i am somewhat at a loss here and i am drawing a complete blank, any help would be appreciated, if you could show some demo with source code that has this feature, than that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses [d3-delaunay](https://github.com/d3/d3-delaunay) which computes a Voronoi diagram allowing to find the closest point.

```
voronoi = d3.Delaunay
  .from(data, d => x(d.x), d => y(d.y))
  .voronoi([0, 0, width, height])
```

You can find a showcase of this technique on the official [Learn D3 documentation](https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-interaction).